# How to display value on textbox from other sheet using vlookup vba

Tags: vba, vlookup

I am trying to display a value from another worksheet using vlookup and userform but it seems not to work

```vb
Private Sub upDate_Click()
Dim sht As String
Dim checkDate As String
Dim checkUpdate As String

'Varible assigned to store combobox value (sheets value on worksheets)
sht = Me.Combobox1.Value
'Uses vlookup to check if the date selected is already on the worksheet (sht)
'which is the value from the combobox. 
checkDate = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.date.Value, 
Worksheets(sht).Range("A:F"), 1, False)
'Uses vlookup to find the login time from the date selected
timeUpdate = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.date.Value,
Worksheets(sht).Range("A:F"), 2, False)
'If the date on the userform matches with a date on the worksheet then the login 
'date will display on texbox what time the user logged in
If Me.date = checkDate Then
Me.time.Value = timeUpdate
End If
```

Comment: Please, state what type of data keeps `date` combo. If it is, or should be a number, VLOOKUP does not match a number with text, even if it looks like a  number. If this is the case, please try `....VLookup(CLng(Me.date.Value),...`, if it is about a `Long` variable, or use `CDbl` in case of a `Double` number. But in such a case, your code should raise an error on the lines trying to return the `VLOOKUP` result... In fact, does your code raise any error?

Comment: it is just a string

Comment: If you use the Excel `VLOOKUP` formula, does it work as you expect?

Comment: I just verified what you told me and you're completely right. My variables were not the same data type. I changed them both to the same data type and it worked! Thanks so much!

Comment: But you said it is about a string. A string is a string...